# SwiftUI - How to calculate offset for HStack that centers subview on screen?

Tags: ios, swiftui, offset, hstack

I have an HStack that has a variable number of subviews. When one of the subviews is tapped, I would like to center that subview on the screen. I want to use `.offset()` to simply move the HStack the correct amount in the proper direction such that the tapped subview becomes centered on the screen. I have the subviews organized in an array that I'm running a `ForEach()` on, and I'm keeping track of the selected subview by setting `selectedButtonIndex` to the index of the array of the tapped subview.

```
@State var buttons: [String] = ["Button"]
@State var selectedButtonIndex: Int = 0
HStack {
  ForEach(0..<buttons.count) { index in
  Rectangle()
    .frame(width: 100, height: 50)
    .onTapGesture {
      selectedButtonIndex = index
    }
    .scaleEffect(selectedIndex == index ? 1.15 : 1) // the selected subview appears slightly bigger than the others
}
.offset(getOffset()) // I need to calculate this such that the selected subview is centered on the screen
```

and I have some button that adds an additional rectangle to the HStack such as:

```
Button("tap") {
    buttons.append("another button")
}
```

**How can I calculate the offset needed on the HStack to center the selected subview?** (what can I put in the function `getOffset()` such that the selected subview gets centered?)

If I need to clarify any additional information, please leave a comment. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think it would be simpler to use ScrollView with ScrollViewReader and `.scrollTo`.

Comment: In the context of the project to which this applies, I cannot use ScrollView - but see the answer I posted for the math.

Answer (score 0):

Simply set the offset to: the width of the button + the padding on each side  * (the number of buttons / 2 - selectedButtonIndex).

In code:

```
110 * CGFloat(buttons.count / 2 - selectedButtonIndex)
```